# How to Generate Private Key in Salesforce?

Tags: oauth2

I am trying to authenticate Salesforce from a third party Application using OAuth 2.0 with JWT and the application requires a private Key for the Salesforce to authenticate. Can Anyone have any idea how to generate Private Key in Salesforce?

Regards.